# How to aggregate the occurence of text file and then graph it Python

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a list

```
top = ['GME', 'MVIS', 'TSLA', 'AMC']
```

And I have a dataset

```
discussion = pd.read_csv('discussion_thread_data.csv')
dt | text
2021-03-19 20:59:49+06 | I only need GME to hit 20 eod to make up
2021-03-19 20:59:51+06 | lads why is my account covered in more red
2021-05-21 15:54:27+06 | Oh my god, we might have 2 green days in a row
2021-05-21 15:56:06+06 | Why are people so hype about a 4% TSLA move
```

So I want to separate the dataframe into separate dataframes where each dataframe would consist of the occurrences of each ticker from the list in the text column.
Here is what I tried

```
check = discussion[discussion['text'].map(lambda txt: any(tag in txt for tag in top))]
```

I get the right output and now I want to graph each occurrence of the row with certain ticker from the list
I want my x axis to be the date and y axis to be the ticker. In other words I want to have 4 separate graphs, each graph would be separate ticker.

Appreciate any help

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean by aggregate the occurence, you can groupby the ticker and apply list. something like df.groupby('ticker')['date'].apply(list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) for all matching values with `\b\b` for word boundaries:

```
top = ['GME', 'MVIS', 'TSLA', 'AMC']

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in top)
df = discussion.set_index('dt')['text'].str.extractall('('+pat+')')[0].reset_index(name='v')
print (df)
                       dt  match     v
0  2021-03-19 20:59:49+06      0   GME
1  2021-05-21 15:56:06+06      0  TSLA
```

For count use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['dt'], df['v'])
print (df1)
val                     GME  TSLA
dt                               
2021-03-19 20:59:49+06    1     0
2021-05-21 15:56:06+06    0     1
```

Last ploting by [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df1.plot()
```

EDIT by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532894/ipython-jupyter-notebook-and-pandas-how-to-plot-multiple-graphs-in-a-for-loop) solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for col in df1.columns:
    df1[col].plot()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Do we have the occurrence of the certain ticker on the y axis?

Comment: @yanbiceps - exactly.

Comment: can you please explain what str.extractall('('+pat+')')[0] does?

Comment: @yanbiceps - it extract all values from `text` by `top` list

Comment: @yanbiceps - there is used `extractall` for possible extract if in one cell is multiple values `top` like `I only need GME to hit 20 eod to make up TSLA`

Comment: also, can you please show me how to make each ticker on the separate graphs, I assume I want to use a for loop but im not getting it correctly. thank you

Comment: it is still on the same graph sorry for being so annoying